# React-Select: How to clear a selection value when another selection value change

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have two variants in my productInfo Component: Material and Size as shown at https://weiwhite.com/product/1

I am trying to clear the value of the size option when the material selection value changes

```
<Select value={size} onChange={setSize} options={sizeOptions} isClearable/>
```

The above code does not clear the previous value of the sizeOptions when material option value changes. below is the whole piece of the code

in productInfo.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useStateValue } from '../StateProvider';
import './ProductInfo.css';
import Select from 'react-select';

function ProductInfo(props) {
    const [Product, setProduct] = useState({})
    const [{basket},dispatch]=useStateValue();

    useEffect(()=>{
        setProduct(props.detail)
      }, [props.detail])
      let minPrice=Product.variants?.map((p) => p.price)
      .sort((a,b)=>a-b)[0]

const [material, setMaterial] = React.useState();
const [size, setSize] = React.useState();

const materialOptions = Product.variants?.map((p) => p.material)
.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
.map((material) => ({ label: material, value: material }))

const sizeOptions = Product.variants?.filter((p) => material && p.material === material.value)
.map((p) => p.size)
.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
.map((size) => ({ label: size, value: size }));

const priceOptions = Product.variants?.filter((p) => size && p.size === size.value && material && p.material=== material.value)
.map((p) => p.price)
.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
.map((price) => ({ label: price, value: price }));

let priceFinal={};
if (priceOptions?.length === 1){priceFinal=priceOptions[0].value}
else {priceFinal=minPrice + "+"}

const addToBasket=() =>{
  //dispatch the item into the data layer
  dispatch ({
     type:'ADD_TO_BASKET',
     item: {
       id: props.detail.id, 
       title: props.detail.title,
       image: props.detail.image,
       price: priceFinal,
     },
   });
};

return (
   <div className='prod__info'>
        
    <h1>{Product.title}</h1>
    <h5 className='prod__desc'>Description</h5>
    <p className='prod__text'>{Product.desc}</p>

    <p className='prod__price'>
            <small>$</small>
            <strong> {priceFinal}</strong>
    </p>
    <br />
    {/* selection option start */}
      <p className='prod__desc'>Material</p>
      <div >
      <Select value={material} onChange={setMaterial} options={materialOptions} isClearable/>
      </div>

      <p className='prod__desc'>Size</p>
      <div >
      <Select value={size} onChange={setSize} options={sizeOptions} isClearable/>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div className='button__cart'>    
      <button className='prod__button'
          onClick={addToBasket}
        >
            Add to basket
    </button>
    </div>

</div>

)
}

export default ProductInfo
```

How to clear the previous size selected value when material selected value changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just make a new function that does both and pass it in for the onClick

```
const changeMaterial = (picked) =>{
  setMaterial(picked.value);
  setSize(null)
}
<Select 
  value={material} 
  onChange={(picked)=>changeMaterial(picked)} 
  options={materialOptions} 
  isClearable
/>
```

or add a useEffect that sets the size back to null when the material changes:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setSize(null)
},[material])
```

Comment: Thank you WebbH, The first solution seems to work, but for some reason, it set both material and size to null. the useEffect() solution works well, and it is exactly what I was looking for.